# Node.js e2e test for endpoint with async task that is not awaited

Tags: node.js, typescript, jestjs, nestjs

I am developing an API in Node.js (NestJS) and have an endpoint which calls two async services. The first one is awaited and its result returned in the response. The second one is left to run in the background and its status is stored and updated in the database.

Something like this:

```
  @Post()
  async test(): Promise<CustomResponse> {
    const result = await firstAsyncService();

    this.secondAsyncService(result);

    return result;
  }
```

What is the usual approach to writting e2e tests in situations like this? I am using jest and so far I just make assertions on the result in my test.

```
it('test', async () => {
  const response = await request(app.getHttpServer())
   .post('/test')
   .send({});

   expect(response).toEqual(something)
});
```

Comment: How would an end-user find out that background task has been completed?

Comment: By polling another endpoint which returns the status of the task by its id.

Comment: So have you considered doing that?

Comment: I thought about polling until its done, but that didn't feel right

Comment: Why not? You should test things as their consumers use them, otherwise you become too coupled to the implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should mock `this.secondAsyncService(result)` in testing and create separate tests for it.

Also leaving promises unhandled is not good approach, consider to rewrite this enpoint and use some [cron](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron) to make hard work and maybe [rabbitMQ](https://www.rabbitmq.com) to handle comunication.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, thanks. Also, any errors caught within secondAsyncService and the task status is updated accordingly.

Comment: Doing actions in background have a lot of sense for me for low priority tasks! Just you need to remember to correctly manage errors as like (I suppose) @hero121 has done in production! I can't understand from the accepted response how to write a test that wait that a mock for `this.secondAsyncService(result)` is called.

Comment: @Elia sinon.js, it supports spy function which is what you looking for https://sinonjs.org/releases/latest/spies/